# как указать независимый путь к папке с изображениями

Tags: bat

Есть флешка на которой есть папка с изображениями и батник который их открывает, нужно чтобы путь был независимый до папки с изображениями, ибо приходится постоянно менять.
Заранее спасибо.

```
for %%v in ("H:\folder\Test\*.jpg") do start "" "%%~v"
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто получите директорию, *из которой* запущен батник вот так:

```
SET currentPath=%~dp0
for %%v in (%currentPath%"folder\Test\*.jpg") do start "" "%%~v"
```

И подставьте в ваш скрипт.